# Keep checking if a function returns true in local storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, local-storage

I'm trying to check if a function returns true in an if/else statement, however I want to keep checking if the function returns true and when it does to execute the code...

How would I go about this? I have tried `setInterval` and `setTimeout` and it won't repeat, unless I'm missing something...

I have also tried a `while` loop but this is inefficient and crashes the browser...

However if I use an `setInterval()` how would I clear it once x returns true?

Here is a snippet of my code for an example.

```js
function x() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("a") === null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

if (!x()) {
    console.log("Returned True!");
    update();
} else {
    console.log("False");
}
```

Comment: Yes, using `while` loop would block the thread and could crash the browser. What didn't work when using `setInterval`? After the code has run, should it continue to check, or stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval()` should work

```
function x() {
    return localStorage.getItem("a") !== null;
}

let interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (x()) {
        console.log("Returned True!");
        update();
        clearInterval(interval);
    } else {
        console.log("False");
    }
}, 500);
```

Comment: Yes I see, but then how would I clear `setInterval()` once x returns true?

Comment: Call `clearInterval()`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks! this worked as intended haha:)

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling your function in the interval like x() or x?

```
function x() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("a") === null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

setInterval(x(), 1000);
setInterval(x, 1000);
```

The first will run once the second till you clear it

Comment: The return value of an interval function is not used. And your first `setInterval()` is wrong, it shouldn't have `()`.

Comment: That is my point

Comment: Oh, I thought you were showing correct code. Answers should not be used to ask questions.